# Customize print export fileName in mui x-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I am using MUI x-data-grid to show a table and export it. When export as print, I need the save-as window to show a custom name. I have tried doing the below:

```
               <DataGrid
                    slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
                    slotProps={{ toolbar: { 
                        csvOptions: { fileName: generateExportFileName() }, 
                        printOptions: { fileName: generateExportFileName() }
                    } }}
                    rows={uniqueProjectsDisplay}
                    getRowId={row => row.projectId}
```

This is working ok for the CSV export, but when exporting as print, it still loads the save as window with default name. What am I missing here?